# How can I generate multiple <Link> element of react router dom with dynamic routes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

How do I generate a multiple  element of react router dom in VS Code in just line? Is it possible?

This what I did:

```
Link*5[to={`${ROUTES.CARS}/$`}]Car{$}
```

The result is:

```
<Link to={`ROUTES.CARS/1`}></Link>
<Link to={`ROUTES.CARS/2`}></Link>
<Link to={`ROUTES.CARS/3`}></Link>
<Link to={`ROUTES.CARS/4`}></Link>
<Link to={`ROUTES.CARS/5`}></Link>
<Car>1</Car>
```

I want to generate like this:

```
<Link to={`${ROUTES.CARS}/1`}>Car 1</Link>
<Link to={`${ROUTES.CARS}/2`}>Car 2</Link>
<Link to={`${ROUTES.CARS}/3`}>Car 3</Link>
<Link to={`${ROUTES.CARS}/4`}>Car 4</Link>
<Link to={`${ROUTES.CARS}/5`}>Car 5</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want with the following.

```
(Link[to={`${ROUTES.CARS}/$`}]{Car $})*5
```

Text is enclosed with `{}` ([docs](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#text)).

Grouping is done with `()` ([docs](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#grouping)).